# Do we really have to free() when we malloc()? What makes it different from an automatic variable then?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free, automatic-storage

The OS will just recover it (after the program exits) right? So what's the use other than good programming style? Or is there something I'm misunderstanding? What makes it different from "automatic" allocation since both can be changed during run time, and both end after program execution?

Comment: Does [this question and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/419022/274261) help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When your application is working with vast amounts of data, you must free in order to conserve heap space.  If you don't, several bad things can happen:

- the OS will stop allocating memory for you (crashing)
- the OS will start swapping your data to disk (thrashing)
- other applications will have less space to put their data

The fact that the OS collects all the space you allocate when the application exits does not mean you should rely upon this to write a solid application.  This would be like trying to rely on the compiler to optimize poor programming.  Memory management is crucial for good performance, scalability, and reliability.

As others have mentioned, `malloc` allocates space in the heap, while auto variables are created on the stack.  There are uses for both, but they are indeed very different.  Heap space must be allocated and managed by the OS and can store data dynamically and of different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ "auto" variables are allocated on the stack. They are destroyed right at the exit from the function. This will happen automatically. You do not need to write anything for this.

Heap allocations (result of a call to `malloc`) are either released explicitly (with a call to `free`) or they are cleaned up when the process ends.

If you are writing small program that will be used maybe once or twice, then it is ok not to free your heap allocations. This is not nice but acceptable.

If you are writing medium or big project or are planning to include your code into other project, you should definitely release every heap allocation. Not doing this will create HUGE trouble. The heap memory is not endless. Program may use it all. Even if you will allocate small amount of memory, this will still create unnedded pressure on the OS, cause swapping, etc.

The bottom line: **freeing allocations is much more than just a style or a good habit**.

Answer (score 2):

It is good programming style and it's more than that. Not doing proper memory management in non-trivial programs will eventually influence the usability of your program. Sure the OS can reclaim any resources that you've allocated/used after your program terminates, but that doesn't alleviate the burden or potential issues *during* program execution.

Consider the web browser that you've used to post this question: if the browser is written in a language that requires memory management, and the code didn't do it properly, how long do you think it would be before you'd notice that it's eating up all your memory? How long do you think the browser would remain usable? Now consider that users often leave browsers open for long periods of time: without proper memory management, they would become unusable after *few* page loads.

Answer (score 2):

If you call a macro for thousand times without using free() then compiler or safe to say system will assign you thousand different address, but if you use free() after each malloc then only one memory address will be given to you every time.
So chances of memory leak, bus error, memory out of bound and crash would be minimum.
Its safe to use free().

Answer (score 2):

An automatic variable is destroyed (and its memory is re-usable) as soon as you exit the scope in which it is defined. For most variables that's much earlier than program exit.

If you `malloc` and don't `free`, then the memory isn't re-usable until the program exits. Not even then, on some systems with very minimal OS.

So yes, there's big difference between an automatic variable and a leaked memory allocation. Call a function that leaks an allocation enough times, and you'll run out of memory. Call a function with an automatic variable in it as many times as you like, the memory is re-usable.

Answer (score 1):

If your program does not exit immediately and you're not freeing your memory you're going to end up wasting it. Either you'll run out of memory eventually, or you'll start swapping to disk (which is slow, and also not unlimited).

Answer (score 1):

automatic variable is on the stack and its size should be known on compilation time. if you need to store data that you don't the size, for example, maintain a binary tree, where the user add and removes objects. beside that stack size might be limited (depends on your target), for example, linux kernel the stack is 4k-8k usually. you also trash the instruction cache, which affects performance,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you absolutely have to use free() after malloc() (as well as closing files and other resources when you're done). While it's true that the OS will recover it after execution, a long running process will leak memory that way. If your program is as simple as a main method that runs a single method then exists, it's probably not a big deal, albeit incredibly sloppy. You should get in the habit of managing memory properly in C because one day you may want to write a nontrivial program that runs for more than a second, and if you don't learn how to do it in advance, you'll have a huge headache dealing with memory leaks.