# Why is there a memory leak? (C)

Tags: c, memory-leaks

```
struct game_t {
    int playercount;
    int board_width, board_height;
    int turn_of;//player number
    int eleminatedPlayer[MAX_PLAYERS];
    int turn;
    int cellcnt[MAX_PLAYERS];

    grid_t** board;

    move_t* moves;
};

game_t* new_game(int width, int height, int playercount)
{
    int i;
    game_t* newgame;
    newgame = (game_t*)calloc(1,sizeof(game_t)); //  <line 181

    newgame->board_height = height;
    newgame->board_width = width;
    newgame->playercount = playercount;
    newgame->turn_of = 0;//Red(player 0)
    zero_fill_arr((char*)newgame->eleminatedPlayer, sizeof(int)*MAX_PLAYERS);
    zero_fill_arr((char*)newgame->cellcnt, sizeof(int)*MAX_PLAYERS);

    newgame->moves = (move_t*)calloc(MAX_MOVES, sizeof(move_t));


    newgame->board = (grid_t**)calloc(width, sizeof(grid_t**));

    for (i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        newgame->board[i] = (grid_t*)calloc(height, sizeof(grid_t));
    }

    return newgame;
}
```

This code has memory leak every time `calloc` is called.
Example :

```
    WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
---------- Block 1 at 0x00EA5B20: 76 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0xE1234C8B, Count: 1, Total 76 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 3264):
    ucrtbased.dll!calloc()
    atoms.c (181): Atoms.exe!new_game() + 0xC bytes
    atoms.c (120): Atoms.exe!main() + 0x1A bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl (64): Atoms.exe!invoke_main() + 0x1B bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl (253): Atoms.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() + 0x5 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl (296): Atoms.exe!__scrt_common_main()
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_main.cpp (17): Atoms.exe!mainCRTStartup()
    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk() + 0x24 bytes
    ntdll.dll!RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification() + 0x439 bytes
    ntdll.dll!RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification() + 0x404 bytes
  Data:
    02 00 00 00    03 00 00 00    03 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    60 05 EB 00    58 6D EB 00                    ....`... Xm......
```

Additional information:

The function is called only once.

This bit of code calls the function : `game_session = new_game(w,h,playerno);`
`game_session` is initialized with NULL(0).

Comment: Because every allocated memory that is not freed is considered a memory leak by leak detectors. This one is.

Comment: @n.m. so, the memory allocated have to be freed at the **end of the code**?

Comment: No, you have to free the memory just before loosing your last pointer to it. That might be at the end of the program.

Comment: You don't *have* to free the memory. A memory leak is *not* (always) fatal. But it's a good practice to free everything, if only to silence the leak detector. For when you have a *real* leak, you risk missing it in the noise of false positives that "don't matter".

Comment: The problem was solved after freeing all the memory before exiting the program. Thanks eveyone!

Comment: @n.m. I'd avoid saying things like that to a beginner. While it's true, it's better to just preach "never allow memory leaks to remain", to help people learn the good habits, and it's generally a good rule of thumb anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to conclude what I learned :

`Visual Leak Detector`, `LeakSanitizer`(which is memory leak detection tool)
detects leak when the memory is not freed when main function returns.
Because mostly, It **IS** leaking. C language does not do [Garbage Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) for you.

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419022/char-x256-vs-char-malloc256sizeofchar) clearly shows which memory is automatically freed and which is not.

> You really don't have to free the memory, if only to silence the leak detector.
>   But it's a good practice to free the memory
>   - n.m.

In my opinion, always free the memory.
Even few bytes of memory leaking could accumulate really fast.

Comment: We are talking about memory allocated once and needed until the very end of the program. You free it, but not because it accumulates.

Comment: @n.m. I think it is a very good reason. Other then that, what is the problem? Security?

Comment: It doesn't accumulate at all, it is only being allocated once and when you free it, the program ends anyway, so it cannot be a reason. As I have said the reason for freeing such memory is keeping your logs clean, because of you don't, you will miss a real problem sooner or later because it will be lost in the noise.