# How to make my code take an input of numbers on one line separated by spaces between, and output the avg of non-repeated numbers?

Tags: c

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int count = 0;

    int size = 0;
    float num[size];

    int i = 0;

    float avg = 0;
    float sum = 0;


    while (scanf("%f",&num) != EOF)
    {
        if ((num[i] != num[i+1]) && (num[i] != num[i-1]))
        {
            sum = sum + num[i];
            size++;
        }
        }
    avg = sum/size;
    printf("%0.2f", avg);
}
```

My input and output:

```
//input
2
2
1
^Z
//output
1.67
```

Correct input and output:

```
2 2 1
^Z
1.50
```

---

### **My question:**

1) How can I make my code prompt input of numbers all on one line separated with spaces in between each input? Right now, my code always starts a new line after entering a number.

2) How can I fix my code so that it only calculates the average of non-repeated numbers? (NOTE: my code has to run no slower than O(nlogn). ) So I can't use nested loops as it will then have a run time of O(n^2).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209148/discussion-on-question-by-patrick-pichart-how-to-make-my-code-take-an-input-of-n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read the numbers into an array `nums`. Let `n` be the number of numbers in the array. This can be done in O(N). I leave this to you.

Secondly, sort the array using a O(N log N) algorithm. I leave this to you.

Finally, we can identify duplicates by simply consulting neighbours. The tricky part is avoiding going out of bounds. Accessing `nums[-1]` or `nums[n]` would result in *Undefined Behaviour*, so we have to avoid that.

We don't need to look ahead and backwards. We want to use a number the first time we encounter it, so we only need to look backwards.

Don't forget to make sure we have at least one number, because we can't divide by zero.

```
if (!n) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Can't find the average of zero numbers.\n");
   exit(1);
}

float sum = 0;
size_t uniques = 0;

for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
   if (i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i-1])
      continue;

   sum += nums[i];
   ++uniques;
}

float avg = sum/uniques;
```

The complexity analysis is O(N + N log N + N) = O(N log N).

(Both of the other answers include O(N^2) solutions

---

As an aside, we can do better than O(N log N).

In practical terms, inserting into a well-written hash table has an amortized performance of O(1), and lookups are O(1). We can use this to devise an O(N) solution to the problem.

Using Perl, since it has such hash tables built-in:

```
@nums
   or die("Can't find the average of zero numbers.\n");

my %seen;      # Hash table.
my $sum = 0;
my $uniques = 0;
for my $num (@nums) {
   next if $seen{$num}++;

   $sum += $num; 
   ++$uniques;
}

my $avg = $sum/$uniques;
```

Comment: Why does the array need to be sorted? Why can't I just check if there are duplicates and then ignore the duplicates and add the non-duplicates and divide by the count

Comment: @PatrickPichart What you suggesting won't work sadly, ikegami is right you need to sort if you want to use his approach. Otherwise you could use a hash table that has O(1) access time to see if the value already exists, meaning it is a duplicate.

Comment: @PatrickPichart if you have any more questions, don't be shy, ask away ;).
Or else you could upvote the most helpful answers, and accept the answer that worked for you, when you run it. :)

Comment: Re "*Why can't I just check if there are duplicates and then ignore the duplicates and add the non-duplicates and divide by the count*", It's a simple way to provide the O(N log N) guarantee.

Comment: @hitter, why won't my method work? when I tried it, the only problem was that it included repeated elements

Comment: Re "*the only problem was [that it didn't do what it was suppose to do at all]*", yeah.

Comment: @PatrickPichart from a quick glance, you did the indexing wrong. You assumed that nearby numbers are only duplicate, while a user could give you this sequence.
`1 5 7 6 3 1`. See how the duplicates are not adjacent?

Comment: And checking all earlier numbers would be O(N^2)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. But even if they entered nearby numbers,  (num[i] != num[i+1]) && (num[i] != num[i-1])  still will not do anything because when I entered 2 2 1, the average was still wrong as it included the extra 2

Comment: We already mentioned the numerous errors in that check: 1) `num[i]` was illegal because you allocated zero elements for `num`. 2) `num[i+1]` was illegal because you allocated zero elements for `num`. 3) `num[i-1]` was illegal because `i-1` is negative. 4) `num[i+1]` is an attempt to access a number you haven't gotten from the scanf yet. 5) Attempting to look forwards and backwards is wrong because it would ignore all instances of duplicate numbers (when you want to ignore all but one).

Comment: Aren't elements allocated(stored in memory) when the user inputs numbers into the scanf function?

Comment: No, scanf doesn't allocate any memory. It writes to memory you already allocated, which was none. (`int size = 0; float num[size];` makes an array with zero elements.)

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems in your code:

- the usage of `num`
- test on `scanf`
- the test of already used number.

---

## the usage of `num`

When you write

```
int size = 0;
float num[size];
```

You do not allocate memory to store numbers.

and

```
while (scanf("%f",&num) != EOF)
```

Is not correct since you are not storing the value read into a float: `gcc` warns:

```
warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘float (*)[(sizetype)(size)]’ [-Wformat=]
```

A more correct way to do would be to write:

```
float num; 
...
while (scanf("%f",&num) != EOF)
```

## test on `scanf`

You test that `scanf` does not return `EOF`, but what if your conversion failed if you do not give a number?

The correct way to test what the user gives, is to check that you have the number of conversion wanted:

```
while (scanf("%f",&num) == 1)
```

## the test of already used number.

Writting

```
if ((num[i] != num[i+1]) && (num[i] != num[i-1]))
```

You test last number (`i`) against past and future number (?!)

You have a simplier approch: have an array to store the already got number. This imply to have a function to test a number has already been got.

**Warning** The current implementation of `is_number_in_array` it very naive and make your program run in O(n). You can easyly replace it with some dichotomic search which is O(log n)

---

So a corrected version of your code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_number_in_array(float num, float *array, int size)
{
    for (int i =0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (num == array[i])
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

#define MAX_NUMBER 50

int main(void)
{
    /* number of number read */
    int size = 0;

    /* number already read */
    float array[MAX_NUMBER] = {};

    /* currently read number */
    float num = 0;

    float avg = 0;
    float sum = 0;

    /* get next number, stop when a conversion failed */
    while (scanf("%f",&num) == 1)
    {
        /* test if number is already in array */
        if (! is_number_in_array(num, array, size )) {
            /* not in array: add it */
            array[size ++] = num;
            sum += num;
        }

        /* Add some test here to check that size is not as big as MAX_NUMBER */
    }

    avg = sum/size;
    printf("%0.2f", avg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let's say there's no repeated numbers. `is_number_in_array` scans 0 elements the first time it's called, 1 element the second time it's called, 2 elements the third time is called, etc. So we have O( 0+1+2+...+(N-1) ) = O( (N-1)*N/2 ) = O( N^2 ) performance. The OP is expected to provide an O( N log N ) algo.

Comment: @ikegami You're right, I put a note in my answer to note this point. I my point of view, before running at full speed, the code must do what is have been asked for. Only after that, you could try to accelerate it. Since it's an homework, I left one hint that could do the trick (dichotomy is O(log n), so the full program will be O(n log n) once the function is changed). Another limitation in my code is the static array to store the previous numbers, but again, it should be better to start small.

Comment: Re "*before running at full speed, the code must do what is have been asked for.*", But before you implement the code, you must choose the correct algorithm. We're not talking micro-optimizations here. The entirely of the code needs to be replaced

Comment: This is making my head hurt, why is coding so hard

Comment: @ikegami yes but it's still an homework. At least now OP has the correct result and needs to think about how to achieve point 2. In my opinion just giving the complete answer won't be helping him understand what is going on, also i really hope his teacher explained to him the various time complexities of algorithms (or at least an introduction of the most common ones like various sorts) before assigning a question with a specific complexity threshold

Comment: @ikegami I agree with John Smith.

Comment: Re "*At least now OP has the correct result and needs to think about how to achieve point 2*", By ignoring everything and starting over...

Comment: Re "*In my opinion just giving the complete answer won't be helping him understand what is going on,*", 100% agree. But posting code that has nothing to with the question doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

This approach saves all integers in an array, as long they are not saved already, as to avoid duplicates.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int bytes_read;
    int size = 1000;

    int i = 0;
    int amount = 0;
    int number = 0;
    // boolean flag to detect duplicate numbers.
    int duplicate = 0;

    int sum = 0;
    float unique_avg = 0;

    // Allocate char / int arrays on the heap.
    // These can be resized with realloc() if needed.
    char* string = (char *) malloc (size);
    int* unique_num = (int *) calloc (2 * size, 0);
    // Declare char pointers to be used will splitting the string.
    char* token; 
    char* rest = string;


    printf ("Please enter a string: ");
    bytes_read = getline (&string, &size, stdin);
    // In case getline fails to get the input.
    if (bytes_read == -1) {
        puts ("error!");

    }
    // getline() read input succesfully.
    else {
        // Iterate over all space separated string tokens.
        while ((token = strtok_r(rest, " ", &rest))){
            // Convert string token to number
            number = atoi(token);
            for(i = 0; i < 2 * size; ++i){
                if(number == unique_num[i]){
                    // Duplicate found.
                    duplicate = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!duplicate){
                unique_num[amount] = number;
                ++amount;
            }
            // Restore value of duplicate for next iteration
            duplicate = 0;
        }
    }
    // Sum all unique numbers.
    for(i = 0; i < amount; ++i){
        sum += unique_num[i];
    }
    // Calculate the avg of unique numbers.
    // Float casting is required for the fractional part of the division.
    unique_avg = (float) sum / (float) (amount);
    // Print the average.
    printf("%f", unique_avg);
    return 0;
}
```

Running this code in console yields with example input of `2 2 1`:

```
Please enter a string: 2 2 1                                                                                                                                                       
1.500000
```

Comment: Yeah, but for each of those N tokens, you search all of unique_num. This approach is inherently broken.

Comment: @ikegami indeed the op must use a sorting approach, in that small part of the code, to achieve a better complexity. I think this a great learning oppurtunity for him/her.

Comment: Re "*indeed the op must use a sorting approach*", There are alternatives. A good hash table is practically amortized O(1) insert/lookup, so you can actually get O(N)

Comment: @ikegami well he/she could implement his/her own hash table as an exercise I guess ;)

Comment: what does malloc and calloc do

Comment: @PatrickPichart It allocates a segment of memory dynamically (in the heap) for getline, 
in this case its 1000 characters.

Comment: @PatrickPichart you can adjust the `size` variable for longer inputs ;)

Comment: @PatrickPichart calloc does the same as malloc but initializes the memory to a value I chose 0 here.

Comment: why is malloc used when scanf can be used?

Comment: @PatrickPichart scanf is an input function as getline.
malloc is used just for the char array, take a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419022/char-x256-vs-char-malloc256sizeofchar